# Show / Hide Div containing php Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, sql-server, ajax

Iam trying to have 3 buttons, and when i press one, it will show the content of a php file. This is what i have done so far:

In the main Html file:

```
<div class="buttons">
<a  class="showSingle" target="1">Logg</a>
<a  class="showSingle" target="2">Saker</a>
<a  class="showSingle" target="3">Rediger Kunde</a>

</div>     

<div id="div1" class="targetDiv"><?php include 'php/loggselect.php'; ?></div>
<div id="div2" class="targetDiv">Saker</div>
<div id="div3" class="targetDiv">Rediger </div>
```

And later in the same file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function(){

        jQuery('.showSingle').click(function(){
              jQuery('.targetDiv').hide();
              jQuery('#div'+$(this).attr('target')).show();
        });
});

</script>
```

Have two problems: When I reload the page, all 3 divs are showing, I have to press one of the "buttons" to only show the content of that spesific button.

The next and biggest problem is that this is working fine as long as it is plain text. But when I use `<?php include 'php/loggselect.php'; ?>` it will no longer show / hide. The php file should display a table with search result from my database. But it does not work when the php only contains `

echo 'testing';
?>` either. Any soulution?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, are you asking for accordion.. Once try it with bootstrap collapse.. See the Accordion example in this link.. 
http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_collapse.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem #1:** You can do,

CSS: `.hiddenDiv {display:none;}`

And add this class to every div

```
$(function(){
    $(".showSingle").eq(0).trigger("click");
});
```

**Problem #2:** Do

```
var _var1 = "variableone";
$("#div1").load('php/loggselect.php?v1='+_var1+'&v2='+_var1);
```

Don't do `<?php ... ?>`

Comment: Thank you, that solved the problem. But do you know how to easily send all my variables from the main Html page to the now loaded php/loggselect.php file? Is it a quick fix to send it lika data in the jquery?

Comment: If it helped considering upvoting it and marking it a right anwerr. :)